# How use the same function that have different ids and a button to use the same function

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code:

Here is the HTML for the navigation:

```
<li><a href="#" id="showOpenWindow">Open... <p class="shortcut">(Ctrl + O)</p></a></li>
```

Here is the window that has the button:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default ui-draggable" style="visibility: hidden" id="openDocument">
<div class="panel-heading ui-draggable-handle" id="openDocumentHandle">Open File <button class="btn btn-default btn btn-default btn-sm windowButtons" id="openDocumentClose"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="filesToOpen">Choose File to Open</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="filesToOpen"></select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="openBtn" onclick="filesystem.loadFloorplan()">Open File</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the JS section:
    var ui = new fp.FloorplanUI(myFloorplan, "ui", "myFloorplan", fp.GUI_STATE);

```
function floorplanUIHideShow(id, div) {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    ui.hideShow(div);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

floorplanUIHideShow('showOpenWindow', 'openDocument', 'openDocumentClose');
```

Each id has a button that needs to use the same ui.HideShow(); function.

I am unable to get this to work..

Any help would be great.

Thanks-

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: unclear what you are asking since it seems to be doing what you state....

Comment: he showOpenWindow is a panel and has a button with a different id. When clicking the button to hide the window, its not working.

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is happening.

Comment: @JonNowak Could you add a small example of the `HTML` to your post please?

Comment: Hard to help without a [mcve] and a more detailed problem description than *"it's not working"*

Comment: I would recommend removing the eventlistener from the function, because everytime you call that function you will add a duplicate event